# Django absolute link appending link content

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've been building a site in Django, and I have URLconf in an app on the site to handle several URLs namespaced under "films" set up as such:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<film_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='details'),
url(r'^(?P<film_id>[0-9]+)/rate/(?P<rating_value>[0-9]+)/$', views.rate,name='rate'),
]
```

The URLs are namespaced here:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^films/', include('poll_test.urls', namespace='films', app_name='poll_test')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Index itself, along with the other pages, function as they should, and can be accessed correctly through the URL bar. The problem arises when I attempt to link between pages in the site. In rate.html (which is linked to the view "rate"), I have:

```
<a href="{% url "films:index" %}"><img src="{% static "logo.png" %}"/></a>
```

The link shows up, but when I attempt to use the link, the page refreshes, changing the URL from  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/films/2` to  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/films/2/#/films/`

It seems to append a # along with the URL I'm attempting to reach from the base url, but, from there, I haven't the slightest idea what's going wrong.

Edit:

It seems that mobile jQuery script that I was importing was causing the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
```

Removing the script import solved the issue.

Comment: Do you have any js code on frontend?

Comment: Try this: `<a href="{% url 'details' index %}"><img src"{% static 'logo.png' %}" /></a>`

Comment: @sobolevn there's no js on the front end, the project's pretty much just css, html, images, and python/django.

Comment: @Gocht I just tried both <a href="{% url 'details' index %}"><img src"{% static 'logo.png' %}" /></a> and <a href="{% url 'films:details' index %}"><img src"{% static 'logo.png' %}" /></a>, both of which return errors.

Comment: please, show us where your url namespace is defined.

Comment: @sobolevn I edited the original post to include the namespace definition.

Comment: @JoshuaThomson it really does look like you have a JS script which does this. Are you 100% sure you didn't put any JS in your page (for example, alongside with CSS)?

Comment: Double check the "js version". It could be even a malware.  Your code seems perfectly fine to me. Try to remove `app_name` just-in-case (because i've never used that and it seems strange to me).

Comment: What's the `index` value in template? Are you using `django-debug-toolbar`?. Your code looks rigth it sould work.

Comment: It seems that I had a mobile jQuery import for icons kicking around, removing it fixed the issue. Thanks for all the help, everyone!